# How can I save an Excel file in SharePoint using Python?

Tags: python, sharepoint

After doing my data cleansing, I would like to export the file and save it in a SharePoint site.

Please can I have some assistance in developing a code that will allow me to do this.

KR
Koysur Miah

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may help with what you are looking for:
https://github.com/iamlu-coding/python-upload2sharepoint

They use a config file to set up the SharePoint configurations, then they use the [shareplum](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python package for saving the file to SharePoint with a given name and folder.

If you need more details, there is also a YouTube tutorial for this at https://youtu.be/BV6SLhOF3zU (this link is from the readme file of the github repository above).

Hope that helps! If it doesn't, sorry!

Comment: Hi Marcus,is it possible to get a call in with you to explain my use case